# Transfer Learning for non-NN models

Tags: supervised-learning, transfer-learning

I have built an non-NN Ensemble Classifier for labeling the content of scanned invoices, for which I used a training set of template invoices.

I would like to use that model to predict labels of similar documents, but I need to add new label types to my model, which haven't been defined or labeled in my original model. I have a smaller amount of pre-labeled documents containing my new label types available.

Is there a way to use my original model as a base and expand it with new label types and a new small trainingsset containing documents with the new labels, as it is possible with Neural Networks?